# Coordinate tags of GeoTIFF are not recognized

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geotag

I received a bunch of GeoTIFFs for which the location is not recognized. It think this is because the tags for storing the coordinates are not recognized as such. Is there a way to rename/convert those into tags that are recognized as coordinates?

[image: Current coordinate tags]